# How to get cdcd (terminal tool to play audi CDs) retrieve tracks titles as freeDB is shutdown

Tags: terminal, audio, music-player

I'm using CDCD tool to play CDs from terminal (in  project involving a RPI and physical buttons to reproduce a hifi system).
Up to recently, it worked fined as CDCD asked a freeDB server for disc data such as artist, tracks titles and so on.

It appears that the FreeDB project as stopped (March 2020) and I wonder if its possible to link CDCD with musicbrainz or to use another cd player (from terminal) which already use musicbranz).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understood FreeDB had simply been replaced by MusicBrainz, also free-to-use.

Comment: Ok ; but my question is about how to use it. in cdcd In can enter 
```
cdcd sites add N  url="???" TYPE
```
and I don't know what URL and TYPE to provide.